# Can a TypeScript Record have optional keys but required values if a key is present?

Tags: typescript

I am building a configuration object where the keys come from a union of known possibilities. If a key exists, then the value should be a required string.
But there's no guarantee that every key will exist on the object, so I need to mark them as optional. However, when I do this, it also marks the value as optional:

```js
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type Config = Partial<Record<Keys, string>>

const config: Config = { 'a': 'some value'}

const value = config.a // value is string | undefined
```

Is there a way for me to express that if the key is present then the value will also be present and it will be a string?

This code does not work but it's an example of what I'd like to do:

```js
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type Config = Record<Partial<Keys>, string>

const config: Config = { 'a': 'some value'}

const value = config.a // value is string
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're explicitly setting type of `config` variable to be `Config`, which is `Partial<Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c', string>>`. Even if you define more specific value `{ 'a': 'some value'}`, TS won't infer its type. It will only check that value satisfies type of variable and that's all.

To both verify that shape of type satisfies some other type and don't make it broader, you can use `satisfies` keyword.

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type Config = Partial<Record<Keys, string>>

const config = { 'a': 'some value'} satisfies Config;

config.a; // string
config.b; // error
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that may be more explicit is the following:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type Config<Type extends string> = {
  [P in Type]?: string;
} 
type PartiallyRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Required<Pick<T, K>>;

const config: PartiallyRequired<Config<Keys>, 'a'> = {
  a: 'some value',
}

config.a // string
config.b // string | undefined
```

The advantage of this is that you explicitly type the keys that you know are defined, while others remain with their original typing, which includes undefined. The downside is... Well... You need to define the keys explicitly, and the other keys will remain undefined even if you set a value in them.